# Назначение прав на удаление файлов из директории

Tags: linux, файловая-система, chmod, vsftpd

Вечер добрый.

В небольшом замешательстве, какие права нужно установить на директорию, что бы из нее можно было удалять пользователем одной группы.

Имеется:

```
~# grep "vsftpd\|app_usr" /etc/passwd
app_usr:x:1001:1001::/home/app_usr:/bin/bash
vsftpd:x:1002:1002::/home/vsftpd:/bin/false

~# grep vsftpd /etc/group
app_usr:x:1001:vsftpd,distribution
vsftpd:x:1002:app_user

~# ls -la / | grep library
drwxr-xr-x+   9 vsftpd app_usr  4096 Dec 18 02:15 library

~# mount | grep " / "
/dev/vda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

Конфиг vsftpd:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
local_root=/library
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
file_open_mode=0777
```

Необходимо установить права для пользователя **app_usr** на удаление файлов, закаченными по FTP в /library, локально создающимися под пользователем **vsftpd**. Пользователь **app_usr** входит в группу **vsftpd** и на оборот.

Пока выдает ошибку:

```
/library# ls -la 123
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 vsftpd vsftpd 0 Dec 18 02:15 123

/library# su app_usr
/library$ rm 123
rm: cannot remove `123': Permission denied
```

---

**UPD**

Проблема в каких то волшебных настройках Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, на Ubuntu 16.04 LTS все удаляется. В обоих проверках были учтены комментарии и советы в обсуждениях.

Comment: Вы выложили много информации, но не показали самую главную - какие права доступа у файлов, которые подлежат удалению.

Если пользователи app_usr и vsftpd входят в одну группу, то для удаления пользователем app_usr файлов, которые были созданы пользователем vsftpd, нужно установить разрешение записи в эти файлы для членов группы. Т.е. нечто вроде 0664. Кроме того, для пользователя app_usr должно быть установлено разрешение исполнения каталога, в котором находятся эти файлы.

Comment: @Sergey Последние  строчки вопроса /library# ls -la 123 -rwxrwxr-x+ 1 vsftpd vsftpd 0 Dec 18 02:15 123

Comment: Отсюда следует, что группа vsftpd имеет полные права на файл 123. Следовательно, что бы пользователь **app_usr**  мог удалить этот файл, надо, что бы он был членом группы **vsftpd**. 

Если же же это условие выполнено, но удаление не проходит, то это означает, что у пользователя **app_usr** нет прав на каое-то поддерево из полного пути к файлу 123. На все элементы дерева (начиная от /)  у него должны быть права "rx", а на последний - "rwx".

Comment: Для удаления файла права на сам файл не играют роли (если на каталоге не установлен бит t). У пользователя должно быть право записи в **каталог** с файлом. ls -ld /library в студию...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для того, чтобы пользователи, входящие в группу, могли создавать и удалять объекты файловой системы внутри некоего каталога, у группы должно быть, помимо права на выполнение (для каталогов оно трактуется особым образом: конечно же, каталог нельзя "выполнить"), еще и право на запись в этот каталог:

```
$ chmod g+w каталог
```

---

если вы пытаетесь удалить файл в этом каталоге, а он недоступен на запись пользователю (ни через один из трёх наборов прав: владельца, группы или всех остальных), то, чтобы избежать диалога подтверждения, можно добавить опцию `-f` (`--force`) к аргументам программы *rm*:

```
$ rm -f каталог/файл
```

Comment: Добрый день, да именно так все и настроено (подробности в вопросе).  работает Java приложение запущенное app_usr, там нет возможности прописать параметры для скрипта.

Comment: *нет возможности прописать параметры для скрипта* - для какого ещё скрипта???

Comment: @Hellseher *именно так все и настроено* - нет, у вас каталог `/library` не доступен для записи пользователям, входящим в группу, которой принадлежит этот каталог (т.е., в группу `app_usr`)

Comment: Для этого - $ rm -f каталог/файл, нет возможности

Comment: во-первых, наверняка у java-обёртки вокруг системного вызова имеется необходимый в данном случае параметр. во-вторых, какие-нибудь "костыли", конечно, можно приделать, но по-хорошему лучше бы начать с того, чтобы отправить ftp на свалку истории, где ему и место.

Comment: Смотрю я на свой вопрос и думаю - спать нужно по ночам. chmod 755 /library != chmod g+rwx.  FTP живее всех живых в киноиндустрии.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70474/discussion-between-hellseher-and-alexander-barakin).